# OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm writing a small script that calculates and plots a rarefaction curve, on a given data.
(As described in Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rarefaction_%28ecology%29)
But I try to plot the function for values **larger than 170** i keep getting the following error: OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')

Here is a sample of code with some data:

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import decimal

def pltCurve():
    data = [[367, 172, 503, 1404, 8, 83, 7, 2, 7, 1, 0, 6, 31, 0, 6, 40, 0, 18, 132, 41, 1, 2, 15, 1, 0, 10, 0, 63, 59, 3, 0, 7, 9, 9, 4, 0, 2, 0, 23, 20, 4, 0, 0, 1, 11, 55, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 11, 0, 10, 6, 0, 4, 0, 443, 2, 49, 29, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 1, 14, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0, 2, 32, 2, 1, 55, 0, 21, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 76, 5, 9, 28, 1, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 6, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 34, 28, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 55, 19, 18, 87, 0, 1, 2, 6, 15, 10, 1, 2]]

    for d in range(len(data)):
        x = np.arange(1,170 , 10)
        y = computeFn(d,x)
        #plt.plot(x,y)
        plt.errorbar(x,y,yerr=0.95)

    plt.show()

def computeFn(i, n):
    N = 4467
    res = []
    r = Decimal(0)
    numOfGroups = 161
    data = [[367, 172, 503, 1404, 8, 83, 7, 2, 7, 1, 0, 6, 31, 0, 6, 40, 0, 18, 132, 41, 1, 2, 15, 1, 0, 10, 0, 63, 59, 3, 0, 7, 9, 9, 4, 0, 2, 0, 23, 20, 4, 0, 0, 1, 11, 55, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 4, 11, 0, 10, 6, 0, 4, 0, 443, 2, 49, 29, 0, 5, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 1, 14, 1, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1, 0, 7, 0, 2, 32, 2, 1, 55, 0, 21, 1, 7, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 76, 5, 9, 28, 1, 0, 72, 0, 0, 0, 0, 61, 6, 5, 0, 5, 2, 0, 1, 9, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 34, 28, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 1, 3, 55, 19, 18, 87, 0, 1, 2, 6, 15, 10, 1, 2]]
    #print N
    for k in n:
        r = (sum((logchoose(N-N_i,k)) for N_i in data[i]))*(logchoose(N,k))**-1
        r = Decimal(numOfGroups) - r
        print r # Debug
        res.append(r)
    return res

def logchoose(ni, ki):

    """
    :rtype : N choose K Function
    """
    try:
        lgn1 = sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ni))
        lgk1 = sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ki))
        lgnk1 = sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ni-ki+1))
    except ValueError:
        #print ni,ki
        raise ValueError
    #print 10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1))
    return Decimal((10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1))))


pltCurve()
```

I've seen solutions to this problem using 'Decimal' module. I've played with it and still the error was raised.
Any suggestions?
Regards.

**Edit:** Here is the exact traceback:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Rarefactor\test.py", line 48, in <module>
    pltCurve()
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Rarefactor\test.py", line 11, in pltCurve
    y = computeFn(d,x)
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Rarefactor\test.py", line 26, in computeFn
    r = (sum((logchoose(N-N_i,k)) for N_i in data[i]))*(logchoose(N,k))**-1
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Rarefactor\test.py", line 26, in <genexpr>
    r = (sum((logchoose(N-N_i,k)) for N_i in data[i]))*(logchoose(N,k))**-1
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Rarefactor\test.py", line 45, in logchoose
    return (10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1)))
OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large')
```

Comment: Don't just tell us the error description, show us the complete traceback, so we know which of these many lines that could raise that error is actually doing so, instead of having to guess.

Comment: Or, much better, give us a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that can reproduce the problem without including all the irrelevant stuff. (For example, if the exception happens before you even get to the plotting functions, the plotting stuff is obviously not relevant. But see the linked help page for a more detailed explanation if it's not obvious to you what you should include.)

Comment: @abarnert Thank you for the response. it seems that the error is being raised at r = (sum((logchoose(N-N_i,k)) for N_i in data[i]))*(logchoose(N,k))**-1. where the function is being calculated. but after trying to use the Decimal module i still get the error.

Comment: Please post the exception with traceback. Answering one question at a time about the exception instead of just showing us so we can see for ourselves just makes it much slower and more painful for anyone who wants to help you.

Comment: @dbliss: I'm not 100% sure it's a dup, because he's trying to use a decent-sized NumPy arrays of floats, not a single float, so the best answer there ("use Decimal instead of float") may not necessarily be appropriate here…

Comment: But meanwhile, the questions says "I've seen solutions to this problem using 'Decimal' module. I've played with it and still the error was raised." Show us the code you played with. It is very definitely possible to process gigantic numbers that would overflow a float by using Decimal; it's also possible to get it wrong in a number of ways so you still get overflows, and it's nearly impossible to guess which of those many ways you might not have done the right thing without seeing what you did. More generally, please read the MCVE link I gave above, and try to edit your question.

Comment: @abarnert just edited with the exact traceback like asked also i have edited with changes using Decimal. I dont see how i can minimize this code further aside from erasing the lines of plotting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your exception comes from this line:

```
return (10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1)))
```

You tried to fix it by using `Decimal` like this:

```
return Decimal(10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1)))
```

But that won't help. Because `lgn1`, `lgnk1`, and `lgk1` are `float` values, you're trying to do the arithmetic with `float` values, and then convert the result to a `Decimal` after it's done. Because the `float` arithmetic overflows, it never gets to the conversion.

What you need to do is make the arithmetic happen on `Decimal` values in the first place. For example:

```
lgn1 = Decimal(sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ni)))
lgk1 = Decimal(sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ki)))
lgnk1 = Decimal(sum(math.log10(ii) for ii in range(1,ni-ki+1)))
```

Now, when you do this:

```
return (10**(lgn1 - (lgnk1 + lgk1)))
```

… you've got `Decimal` arithmetic, not `float`, and it won't overflow (as long as your `Decimal` context is large enough for these numbers, of course).

But you probably want to push the `Decimal` as high up the chain as possible, not as low as possible. In this case, that's only one level up—calling `math.log10` on an integer gives you a `float`, but calling the `log10` method on a `Decimal` gives you a `Decimal`, so:

```
lgn1 = sum(Decimal(ii).log10() for ii in range(1, ni))
```

---

Meanwhile, for future reference:

> I dont see how i can minimize this code further aside from erasing the lines of plotting.

Well, first, why not erase the lines of plotting then?

But, more importantly, you know that the exception happens on the last line of the `logchoose` function, and you know (or could know, by, say, adding a `print ni, ki` or running in the debugger) what arguments cause it to raise. So you could reduce the whole thing to the `logchoose` definition plus `print logchoose(273, 114)` (or whatever the arguments are).

Besides being a lot shorter, this would also completely take `numpy` and `matplotlib` out of the equation, so people who know nothing about those libraries but know a lot about Python (which is the vast majority, and includes people who are smarter than me, dbliss, and Nimrodshn, or at least smarter than me) could solve your problem.

Comment: that helped me like 7 years later. Pretty sick. Little question: decimal.getcontext().prec = n, what on my computer is limiting n. RAM, CPU,  GPU, ...? I would want to say RAM but i'm not sure and curious.